# select data from two mysql tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  COUNT(*) as count
from tickets
where
  status = :status 
  and DATE(closed_timestamp) = '".date("Y-m-d")."' 
group by assigned_to 
order by count(*) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

but i want to remove the `closed_timestamp` column from the `tickets` table and run the query based on the `datetime` column in the `ticket_updates` table

`ticketnumber` in the `tickets` table is equal to the `ticketnumber` (multiple rows) in the `ticket_updates` table

so it should run the above query without the `closed_timestamp` column and base it on the latest `datetime` value in the `ticket_updates` table

**EXAMPLE**

there are 2 rows in the tickets table where `ticketnumber = 1234` and `5678`

there are 3 rows in the `ticket_updates` table.. two rows have `ticketnumber = 1234` and the other has `ticketnumber = 5678`

i want to show all the rows from tickets where `status = 'Completed'` and the last update (`ticket_updates` table) equals the current date *(2014-05-19)*

Comment: use `JOIN` to join those tables

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` query like below,

```
SELECT 
  t.*,
  COUNT(t.*) as count
from tickets as t
LEFT JOIN ticket_updates as tu
ON tu.ticketnumber = t.ticketnumber
where
  t.status = :status 
group by t.assigned_to 
order by count(t.*) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: i tried running your query but i get a syntax error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as count
from tickets as t
LEFT JOIN ticket_updates as tu
ON tu.ticketnumb' at line 3 

i changed :status to 'Completed'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets t
JOIN (
  SELECT ticketnumber
  FROM ticket_updates
  WHERE DATE(datetime) = CURDATE()
) u
ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber
WHERE status = 'Completed'
```

Comment: check my question. i said i want to remove the closed_timestamp column]

Comment: you mean remove from the table? I thought remove from the where clause, my bad

Comment: i want to remove it from the where clause and eventually it will not exist in the table. you say that but you still included it in your where clause

Comment: I think total removal will not be possible, as you need a date to join the ticket_updates table

Comment: it doesnt seem to be returning any rows. let me show an example in my question...

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM tickets t
join ticket_updates u on t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber
where DATE(u.datetime) = '".date("Y-m-d")."' 
and t.status = 'Completed'

The important part is `join ticket_updates u on t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber`

The rest depends on how exactly your columns are defined (types, unique, nullable ...)

Comment: ok, thats now showing multiple rows but way too many. it should only be showing 2 and i want to group by assigned_to in the tickets table. i added this in but its showing loads of rows from the ticket_updates table

Comment: add `and t.closed_timestamp = u.datetime` to the `join  on` clause or `and DATE(u.datetime) = = '".date("Y-m-d")."` to the `where clause`

Comment: i dont want to use the closed_timestamp column!

Comment: there must be a query i can use that says select from tickets where the last added row from the ticket_updates table is today and where ticketnumber from tickets = ticketnumber from ticket_updates and group by assigned_to in the tickets table

Comment: edited answer.

I think "last added row" is irrelevant, the dates simply have to match